# C# - DateTime.Parse from string not working

Tags: c#, datetime

I got a DateTime in a string format :

```
"05/30/2014 12:00:00"
```

I want to create a DateTime object from this string by doing this :

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
```

However, I've got an error which says that this method has some invalid argument :

```
Error 1 - The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments
```

When I'm reading the doc, a string argument is definitely a good argument. What's wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: You're declaring `startDate` to be a `DateTime`... but trying to use it as a string, in the initialization for it. I suspect you've got a different variable which is actually your string.

Comment: Your question has an error in it, and is almost certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can find more info on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) and pass the format you have in date string. The current culture  might have date form in which day comes before month like dd/mm/yy.

You are passing the same variable to ParseExact method that you have declared for DateTime. Change the name of DateTime object.

```
DateTime dtStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can read the article from [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get more understanding for declaring the format for parsing the date string.

Comment: I suspect you want HH rather than hh... but if the OP is getting a compile-time error, then this won't compile either. (Hint: look at the variable you're declaring, and the one you're passing in...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing in your variable to parse before you have initialised it.

So you could have:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("05/30/2014 12:00:00");
Console.WriteLine(startDate);
```

Or, you could have:

```
String dateToParse = "05/30/2014 12:00:00";
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(dateToParse);
Console.WriteLine(startDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your date inside a string variable and then use following:

```
DateTime.Parse(STRINGVARIABLE);
//Which means following
//DateTime.Parse("05/30/2014 12:00:00");
```

In your code, you are trying apply the format to the variable of type DateTime. Or if you want to apply the format directly to DateTime variable then you can simply write following:

```
DateTime.Parse("05/30/2014 12:00:00").ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```